# Array value to mathemaical result

Tags: php, arrays, math

I have a array like the following:

```
Array(
[0] => 3
[1] => *
[2] => 15
[3] => -
[4] => 15)
```

I need the array values to display result like the structure in PHP.
that is 3*15-15.
the result should be 30.
How can I do that?

Comment: It is in PHP language sir.

Comment: In PHP language sir.

Comment: What have you tried, and just where are you stuck? Please be more specific as to your output: do you want a "display result" of the expression or of the numeric value? What format is the result to be in?

Comment: need to display result of numeric value  and expression. as you see the values of array are like 3, *, 15, -, 15. so i need the result of the expression 3*15-15.

Comment: You should try to solve your problem first, then ask on SO.

Comment: I tried my maximum, also googled about the problem . but no result.

Comment: how about operations precedence and parentheses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in such way. It's just a draft:

```
$arr = [ 3, '*', 15, '-', 15];

$first = reset($arr);
while ($operation = next($arr)) {
  $second = next($arr);
  switch ($operation) {
    case '*': $first *= $second;
              break;
    case '-': $first -= $second;
              break;
  }
}

echo $first;
```

Comment: Thanks. your draft is awesome.

Comment: Thnks. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = array( 3,'*', 15, '-', 15);
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
    $str .=$array[$i];

}

 eval( '$result = (' . $str. ');' );
 echo $result;
```

linke :-> http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Be care full before using eval, in your code